# JPA repository doesn't perform update when called in Catch clause before throwing exception

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-data-jpa

I am facing a strange issue, I have created an Async method to do some processing and in case everything goes fine I make an Update through JPA repository to set a Flag in DB to True.

In case there is an exception I call the repository to update with flag False and then rethrow the exception. Here is the funny thing, when there is an exception the update doesn't occur!

Sample:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class MyAsyncService{
  @Async
  public void asyncMethod() throws Exception{
    try{
        //Some Logic
        myrepo.update(true);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        myrepo.update(false);
        throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

There is no exception at all. If I remove the `throw e` it works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Transactional annotation type is generally directly comparable to
>   Spring's RuleBasedTransactionAttribute class, and in fact
>   AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource will directly convert the data to
>   the latter class, so that Spring's transaction support code does not
>   have to know about annotations. If no rules are relevant to the
>   exception, it will be treated like DefaultTransactionAttribute
>   (rolling back on RuntimeException and Error but not on checked
>   exceptions).

It's a bad practice to update transaction if any errors occurred, but for solving your problem you can add 
`@Transactional(noRollbackFor= Exception.class)` and ignore this exception. The trx will not rollback

Answer (score 1):

If your exception is a RuntimeException Spring will rollback the transaction.

From the docs:

> Although EJB container default behavior automatically rolls back the
>   transaction on a system exception (usually a runtime exception), EJB
>   CMT does not roll back the transaction automatically on anapplication
>   exception (that is, a checked exception other than
>   java.rmi.RemoteException).
>
> While the Spring default behavior for
>   declarative transaction management follows EJB convention (roll back
>   is automatic only on unchecked exceptions), it is often useful to
>   customize this behavior.

Read more here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative